# SimpleXMLElement->array, in_array not working

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

`print_r($xml);`:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [groupId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
        )
)
```

`in_array(1, $xml->groupId)` on this doesn't work: `PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

`print_r((array)$xml->groupId);` prints only first element in array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

How can I **properly** check for an element existing in `groupId`, **without** a hack like `json_decode(json_encode($xml->groupId));` ?

XML `print_r($xml->asXML());`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<return>
    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <groupId>5</groupId>
    <code>13</code>
</return>
```

**Why does `(array)$xml->groupId`** .... oh ... lol :-) Now I see the problem.... thanks

Comment: can you also post your xml? try $xml->{groupId}

Comment: see [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/) this would be help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><return><groupId>1</groupId><groupId>5</groupId>
    <code>13</code></return>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
if(in_array(1, (array)$xml)) {
    echo 'got it';
}else {
    echo 'not get';
}
```

Comment: When I looked at the XML, I noticed it is not like I expected. `(array)$xml` was correct, not `(array)$xml->groupId` :-) Can you update the answer a little bit for me to accept, thank you.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks i am confused on my answer cause you have also a good ranking on stack

Comment: No problem, I was confused too ;) Have a nice day